# How to add parse.com php sdk to symfony

Tags: php, symfony, parse-platform

I have project in Symfony2(php framework) and I use parse.com as backend(database etc.) but I don't know how to add parse php sdk to Symfony. I add it to php project without any framework using [parse quickstart](https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/php) an it works.
Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add this line to the `require` block of your `composer.json`.

```
"parse/php-sdk" : "1.1.*"
```

You can find the `composer.json` in the root of your Symfony project.

After that, cd to the project directory in your command line and run:

```
composer update
```

Read more about composer here:
https://getcomposer.org/

Read more about installing and using the Parse PHP SDK here:
https://github.com/parseplatform/parse-php-sdk

Comment: Make sure to use version `1.2.*` instead, as that line contains the necessary support for setting up your own parse-server.